# Client.put and Client.get requests fail when using web.py

Tags: python, http, get, put, web.py

I am building a relatively simple site for images and am building a login and registration system.

```
import porc
MY_API_KEY = '<REDACTED>'
client = porc.Client(MY_API_KEY)
dbUsername = dbinfo['username']
username = u'test'
if dbUsername != username:
    send = client.put('bstego', u'testy', {
        "username": u'testy',
        "email": u'testing@test.com',
        "URL": 'test.test'
})
success = client.get('bstego', u'testy')
print "Received "+success["username"]
```

The above code works and delivers perfectly. However, in my implementation with web.py if I use almost the exact verbatim code, I get a NoneType.
[image: Error]

Comment: Please add more context, what does web.py contain?How do you execute web.py? Is web.py running on top of any framework?

Comment: No framework. Web.py is standalone as per the Learning Python the Hard Way book/tutorial.

Comment: and erm... I'm a student and decided to use cloud9 to host my project, and that's the default, and frankly I don't know much about it.